# How can I get the command-line output of a DOS tool using Perl?

Tags: perl, command-line, ftp, stdout

I want to meassure the throughput of a link using Windows build-in FTP tool inside a Perl script. Therefore the script creates the following command script:

```
open <ip>
<username>
<password>
hash
get 500k.txt
quit
```

Afterwards I run the command script using the following Perl code:

```
system(@args);
@args = ("ftp", "-s:c:\\ftp_dl.txt");
system(@args);
```

If I run the command inside a DOS-box the output looks like this:

```
ftp> open <ip>
Connected to <ip>
220 "Welcome to the fast and fabulous DUFTP005 ftp-server :-) "
User (<ip>:(none)):
331 Please specify the password.

230 Login successful.
ftp> hash
Hash mark printing On  ftp: (2048 bytes/hash mark) .
ftp> get 500k.txt
200 PORT command successful. Consider using PASV.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 500k.txt (14336 bytes).
#######
226 File send OK.
ftp: 14336 bytes received in 0.00Seconds 14336000.00Kbytes/sec.
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
```

To be able to get the throughput I need the extract that line:

```
 ftp: 14336 bytes received in 0.00Seconds 14336000.00Kbytes/sec.
```

I'm not very familiar with Perl. Does anybody have an idea how to get that line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use either [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) in pipe mode:

```
open($filehandle, "$command|") or die "did not work: $! $?";
while(<$filehandle>)
{
#do something with $_
}
```

or use backticks:

```
my  @programoutput=`$command`
```

Comment: Note, however, that both of these only capture standard output of the command. You have to do a bit of extra work to get standard error. I don't know which ones the DOS ftp command uses though.

Answer (score 2):

You [can't get the output with `system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#Why-can%27t-I-get-the-output-of-a-command-with-system()%3F).

Instead use bactkicks:

```
my $throughput = 0;
my $output = `ftp -s:c:\\ftp_dl.txt`;
if (($? == 0) && ($output =~ /([\d+\.]+)\s*K?bytes\/sec/m)) {
    $throughput = $1;
}
```

`$output` will contain all the lines from the execution of the `ftp` command (but not any error message sent to `STDERR`).
Then we check if `ftp` returned success (`0`) and if we got a throughput somewhere in the output.
If so, we set `$throughput` to it.

This being Perl, there are many ways to do this:

You could also use the [`Net::FTP`](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/libnet-1.22/Net/FTP.pm) module that supports Windows to deal with the file transfer and use a timing module like [Time::HiRes](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/Time-HiRes-1.9719/HiRes.pm) to time it and calculate your throughput.

This way you won't depend on the ftp program (your script would not work on localised version of Windows for instance without much re-work, and you need to rely on the ftp program to be installed and in the same location).

Answer (score 2):

See [perlfaq8](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html), which has several answers that deal with this topic. The ones you probably need for this question are:

- [Why can't I get the output of a command with system()?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#Why_can_t_I_get_the_)
- [How can I capture STDERR from an external command?](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#How_can_I_capture_ST)

Also, you might be interested in some of the IPC (Interprocess Communication) Perl modules that come in the standard library:

- IPC::Open2
- IPC::Open3

Some of the Perl documentation might also help:

- [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html) - Perl interprocess communication
- [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) - Perl open tutorial

If you're not familiar with the Perl documentation, you might check out my [Perl documentation documentation](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=perl+documentation+documentation).

Good luck,

Answer (score -2):

You should try and use [libcurl](http://curl.netmirror.org/libcurl/perl/) which is more suited for the task.

There is an [easy to use API](http://search.cpan.org/~crisb/WWW-Curl-3.02/Easy.pm.in)